# Does a server use bandwidth when connecting to itself?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails, mariadb

I have a dedicated server (CentOS 7) with Storm on Demand. I have a rails application running on the server served by nginx and unicorn. I'm using MariaDB on the same server. The rails app handles hundreds of thousands of images per year (sometimes per month). I have another rails app on the server that uses the same database and handles file uploads and processing.

During high upload times, I move the upload app to another dedicated server and update DNS settings for the upload app's domain in order to offload the bandwidth, cpu, and memory problem from the main app.

The database.yml for the main app is:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: main_app_production
  pool: 5
  username: application
  password: ****
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

The database.yml for the upload app is:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  host: host.domain.com # main server's fully qualified domain name
  port: 3306
  database: main_app_production
  pool: 5
  username: application
  password: ****
```

The reason for the host and port settings on the upload server is so that it's irrelevant to the app whether it's running on the main server or on the temporary high volume server.

My question is, when the upload app is running on the same server as the main app (and therefore the same server as the database) does it use my limited bandwidth from Storm to have it connect through the domain and port instead of through the default localhost? How could I test this?

Comment: Does host.domain.com resolve to an IP that is assigned to the server (ie, visible in `ip addr show`)?

Comment: yes if you use the FQDN and it points to an external interface (a non-loopback ip address), you will use bandwidth.

Comment: Andrew, yes it does. Would it help to resolve host.domain.com to local host in /etc/hosts on the main server?

Answer (score 0):

You can test by unplugging the network cable. If you can still ping the ip-address of the server despite the link being down, you won't be using using your paid-for bandwidth when communicating with that IP-address.

AFAIK there is no reason you would be using bandwidth, except maybe for resolving when the ip-address and hostname you're using are not defined in `/etc/hosts`. Any configured ip-address is destined locally and won't go through the wire.

Possibly of interest is the [Host Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model) of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, if a destination IP is local, traffic destined for it will never leave the host.  One thing to keep in mind is that you can set a DNS A record to point to localhost (127.0.0.1).  As long as the only thing that's resolving that host name is on the same box then there's no reason not to just set it to resolve to localhost.